# Make a timeline by using vis.js but it cannot change x-axis value

Tags: timeline, vis.js

I am using vis.js to draw a timeline, like the picture below,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eUio.png

Can I change the x-axis value and type the value manually? Since I do not want to use date. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your own formatting of the labels on the axis, but it is a *time* line and is not suitable for displaying values instead of dates.